# Finding the period in a Markov Chains related situation.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let there be two vases with total 4 balls in them. At every step a ball is chosen with a uniform probability to every ball, and is put in the other vase. Let us consider the number of balls in vase **$a$** as the possible states. What is the period of the chain?

What I did is: There are five state that I will denote as $s_0,s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4$, $s_i$=$i$ balls in vase a. I can go from $s_i$ to $s_{i+1}$ or $s_{i-1}$(if $i\ne 0$). I can't however go from $s_{i}$ to $s_{i+k}$ or $s_{i-k}$ if $k>1$. The shortest orbit number of steps from one state to itself is 2. Therefore, I have to check if there are orbits with odd number of steps. I don't know how to show that. Another thing: I have to take gcd of the all the orbits lengths, but is there another condition required for this gcd to actually be the period? Like, a connection between any pair of states? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that the number of balls in the vase of your choice always changes parity at each step --- that is, if it's odd, it becomes even, whereas if it's even, it becomes odd. So, after an odd number of steps, you have a different parity than you had before those steps, and in particular, you can't have the same distribution. Now, I don't know what you mean by "period" --- the chain doesn't have to be periodic, the way I use that word. But some state must repeat, and since there are only 5 states, the longest you can go before a repeat is 6 steps. Does that help?

Comment: Google 'Ehrenfest urn model'. Binomial stable distribution. Suppose 2 balls in each urn at time 0. So initial state is 2. Move a ball, state at step 1 is odd. Move a ball, state at step 2 is even. Continue forever. No absorption. Write transition matrix. Take successive powers. Never get all positive elements. Not ergodic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "I don't know what you mean by "period"" Googling `period markov chain` might help.

Comment: @Did, it might. OP responding to comments might help, too.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "OP responding to comments might help, too." On this I am unequivocally with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the graphical representation of this Markov chain, you get $s_0 \leftrightarrow s_1 \leftrightarrow s_2 \leftrightarrow s_3 \leftrightarrow s_4$. This is a bipartite graph, since there is no possible transition within $s_0, s_2, s_4$ or $s_1, s_3$ (including e.g. $s_1 \rightarrow s_1$).

Consequently, the period of the chain is 2.